# tcp/ip monitor

Tags: eclipse, tcp, monitor

in eclipse, i have a weblogic server running, and a j2ee application deployed to it.
the application is serving on port 7001.
i want to hook the monitor up to the application, i do not know what ports to use.
i think i know what to put in for the Host Name (localhost:7001), but not sure of what to use for type and Local Port. in the proeferences, what is meant by Local Port.
does it matter if i start the monitor before or after the application is running?
my goal is the watch the traffic as i login, from my local machine via a browser, and surf to other parts of the application.
thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The monitor basically acts as a proxy. The local monitoring port is the port you will send requests to the monitor on. It can be any free port (7002, for example).

The host name, port, and type describe what you want the monitor to proxy to. In your case, it would be localhost, 7001, and HTTP.

Then, you would use your browser to access localhost:7002, and the proxied requests and responses would be displayed in the monitor.

Answer (score 12):

if your original url for webservice is say `http://abc.xyz:5674/ws/wsdl:linkaction`

then do these settings for tcp/ip monitor:

```
local monitoring port:8888
hostname:abc.xyz
port:5674
type:http
Start it
```

And change the webservice url to "http://localhost:8888/ws/wsdl:linkaction"

Run your client.java as java application

so your request will go through tcp/ip proxy and you can see the soap messages.

Answer (score 0):

Normal SOAP envelope flows
1. Client ----> SOAP envelope ----> Server:9999

2. Server:9999 ----> SOAP envelope ---> Client

To intercept SOAP envelope, you can host another server (“TcpMonitorServer”) in between client and server, see new flows :

1. Client ----> SOAP envelope ----> TcpMonitorServer:8888
2. TcpMonitorServer:8888 --> SOAP envelope ---> Server:9999
3. Server:9999 ----> SOAP envelope ---> TcpMonitorServer:8888
4. TcpMonitorServer:8888 ----> SOAP envelope ---> Client

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-trace-soap-message-in-eclipse-ide/)